# Sorting in Javascript with special characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with the following values

```
asd sdf dsdf 1sadf *sdf !sdf @asdf _asd .sadf (sadf )sadf #sadf 
^asdf &asdf %asdf -sadf =sadf +sadf -sdf
```

and i want to sort it in javascript in the following way in to three parts.

1. word starting from special character
2. word starting from digit
3. word starting from alphabets.

So this should be the sequence of the sorted array.

**EDIT**:
Here's a function that I've been experimenting with:

```
function naturalSort(a, b) {
   a = a.path.toLowerCase();
   b = b.path.toLowerCase();
   var re = /(^-?[0-9]+(\.?[0-9]*)[df]?e?[0-9]?$|^0x[0-9a-f]+$|[0-9]+)/gi,
  sre = /(^[ ]*|[ ]*|[_]*$)/g,
  dre = /(^([\w ]+,?[\w ]+)?[\w ]+,?[\w ]+\d+:\d+(:\d+)?[\w ]?|^\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}|^\w+, \w+ \d+, \d{4})/,
  hre = /^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i,
  ore = /^0/,
   // convert all to strings and trim()
  x = a.toString().replace(sre, '') || '',
  y = b.toString().replace(sre, '') || '',
   // chunk/tokenize
  xN = x.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/, '').replace(/^\0/, '').split('\0'),
  yN = y.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/, '').replace(/^\0/, '').split('\0'),
   // numeric, hex or date detection
  xD = parseInt(x.match(hre)) || (xN.length != 1 && x.match(dre) && Date.parse(x)),
  yD = parseInt(y.match(hre)) || xD && y.match(dre) && Date.parse(y) || null;
   // first try and sort Hex codes or Dates
   if (yD)
    if (xD < yD) return -1;
    else if (xD > yD) return 1;
   // natural sorting through split numeric strings and default strings
   for (var cLoc = 0, numS = Math.max(xN.length, yN.length); cLoc < numS; cLoc++) {
    // find floats not starting with '0', string or 0 if not defined (Clint Priest)
    oFxNcL = !(xN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(xN[cLoc]) || xN[cLoc] || 0;
    oFyNcL = !(yN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(yN[cLoc]) || yN[cLoc] || 0;
    // handle numeric vs string comparison - number < string - (Kyle Adams)
    if (isNaN(oFxNcL) !== isNaN(oFyNcL)) return (isNaN(oFxNcL)) ? -1 : 1;
    // rely on string comparison if different types - i.e. '02' < 2 != '02' < '2'
    else if (typeof oFxNcL !== typeof oFyNcL) {
     oFxNcL += '';
     oFyNcL += '';
    }
    if (oFxNcL <= oFyNcL) return -1;
    if (oFxNcL >= oFyNcL) return 1;
   }
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: ....And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Just try, it's not as much difficult.

Comment: So special characters before numbers. But is `@` before `#`? What's the order of characters? You must not want ASCII order, since `=` is after numbers in ASCII. @Ravi, you'll need to show that you've at least tried something. Effort is valued here.

Comment: i have tried this functionality.. 

function(a,b){
   return a>b? 1 : (a<b ? -1 : 0);
}

Comment: @JonathanM i can understand but i had tried a lot and couldnt get proper answer..!

Comment: @Ravi, then tell us what order of characters is required. Is `&` before or after `=`? What about all the others?

Comment: Hey Jonathan check this link..here is the function..

http://codeassistant.blogspot.in/2012/06/test-sort-function.html

Comment: @Ravi. Please don't give a link. Links die and this question will not be helpful for later viewers with the same type of problem. Instead, edit the code into your post. I've done that for you now. Please tell us why the posted code won't work for you.

Comment: Hey Jonathan..

i had already tried by changing this line..

if (isNaN(oFxNcL) !== isNaN(oFyNcL)) return (isNaN(oFxNcL)) ? -1 : 1;..

but it didnt worked out...

The elements starting from digits coming at third place..!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To be honest, I have no idea what your posted function does ... at all.

The following approach compares strings on their first character, using positional occurrence. Strings with the same first character are sorted regularly.

Btw, didn't test for empty strings.

```
function MySort(alphabet)
{
    return function(a, b) {
        var index_a = alphabet.indexOf(a[0]),
        index_b = alphabet.indexOf(b[0]);

        if (index_a === index_b) {
            // same first character, sort regular
            if (a < b) {
                return -1;
            } else if (a > b) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        } else {
            return index_a - index_b;
        }
    }
}

var items = ['asd','sdf', 'dsdf', '1sadf', '*sdf', '!sdf', '@asdf', '_asd', '.sadf', '(sadf', ')sadf', '#sadf', '^asdf', '&asdf', '%asdf', '-sadf', '=sadf', '+sadf', '-sdf', 'sef'],
sorter = MySort('*!@_.()#^&%-=+01234567989abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');

console.log(items.sort(sorter));
```

Output:

```
["*sdf", "!sdf", "@asdf", "_asd", ".sadf", "(sadf", ")sadf", "#sadf", "^asdf", 
 "&asdf", "%asdf", "-sadf", "-sdf", "=sadf", "+sadf", "1sadf", 
 "asd", "dsdf", "sdf", "sef"]
```

Comment: Hey Jack ....you are great man...it solved my problem...Thanks a lot dude... you are awsome...!

Answer (score 9):

Two easy solutions:

**using Intl.Collator**

```
myArray.sort(Intl.Collator().compare)
```

**using localeCompare**

```
myArray.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
```

**Intl.Collator** is more perfomant

Answer (score 1):

This could also work:

```js
function sortArray(a, b) {
  const digitRegex = /^\d/;
  const alphabetRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]/;
  const symbolRegex = /^[^\w\s]/;
  
  const scoreA =  symbolRegex.test(a) * 1 || digitRegex.test(a) * 10 || alphabetRegex.test(a) * 100;
  const scoreB =  symbolRegex.test(b) * 1 || digitRegex.test(b) * 10 || alphabetRegex.test(b) * 100;
  
  if (scoreA !== scoreB) {
    return scoreA - scoreB;
  }
  
  if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  return 0;
}

const a = ['def', '%rec', '456', '^we', '123', 'abc'].sort(sortArray);

console.log(a);
```