# Complex strings of array sorting using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, user-interface

I have a requirement to sort array of strings which contains numbers, letters and symbols in which the strings starting with letters will be on top followed by numbers and then symbols.

An example:

```
let stringArray =['def', '%rec', '456', '^we', '123', 'abc']

//desired output
['abc', 'def', '123', '456', '%rec', '^we']
```

Code that I am using

```
stringArray.sort(function(a, b){ return a - b })
```

Comment: you want to compare  string  without symbols characters?

Comment: What issue are you having? Please supply a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The answer from Jack seems to be perfect for your needs <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951167/sorting-in-javascript-with-special-characters>

Comment: **Your desired output does not correspond to any logical order**. at least because in ascii the numbers are before the letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort function will give you the results you want; it checks for matching types of string (starting with alphabetic, numeric or symbol) and compares directly if so, otherwise it returns a value appropriate to the desired ordering of alphabetic, numeric or symbol in the result. Note that I've assumed that you want to sort numeric strings in numeric order (i.e. `20` comes before `100`), if that is not the case, replace

```
return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
```

with

```
return a.localeCompare(b);
```

```js
const msort = (a, b) => {
  if (a.match(/^[a-z]/i)) {
    if (b.match(/^[a-z]/i)) {
      return a.localeCompare(b);
    } 
    else {
      return -1;
    }
  } else if (a.match(/^[0-9]/)) {
    if (b.match(/^[0-9]/)) {
      return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
    } 
    else if (b.match(/^[a-z]/i)) {
      return 1;
    }
    else {
      return -1;
    }
  } 
  else {
    if (b.match(/^[^a-z0-9]/i)) {
      return a.localeCompare(b);
    } 
    else {
      return 1;
    }
  }
}

input = ['def', '%rec', '456', '^we', '123', 'abc'];

input.sort(msort);
console.log(input);
```

Comment: How can I check the above sequence to work for the whole string

Comment: @SaikatSaha I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: First of all Thanks for the solution, the solution sequence applies for the first character, can it be applied for the whole length, in case the string is very complex i.e., (a16y# and a15y%) then a15y% should come above the other

Comment: @SaikatSaha `a15y%` will sort before `a16y#` because `5` comes before `6`. I think what you're trying to explain might take more than can reasonably fit into comments. I would suggest asking another question - you can refer back to this one - and give a more detailed explanation of how you want to sort and examples of values that are not sorting the way you want them to with this code.

Comment: Yes @Nick you are right let me give you a proper example(a16y#, a15y%, aa5y%, ab5y%), as per above solution(a15y%, a16y#, aa5y%, ab5y%) but what I am expecting is it should be applied throughout the string that means (aa5y%, ab5y%, a15y%, a16y#)

Comment: @SaikatSaha I'm still not completely with you. It seems like it might be too complicated to explain through comments, I would suggest asking another question.