# Sorting by Alphabetic, then Symbols in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

What would be the best way of sorting by Alphabetic, then symbols in javascript/node? I've used this function below to sort it alphabetically, however the "_text" is sorted at the top.

```
const items = {
"objectb": "text",
"objecta": "one",
"_text": "two",
"objectc": "three"
}

const ordered = Object.keys(items).sort().reduce(
        (obj, key) => {
            obj[key] = items[key];
            return obj;
        }, {}
    );

// This produces the sorted object, however the symbol key is sorted at the top, whereas I would like it at the bottom.

RETURNS:
{
"_text": "text",
"objecta": "one",
"objectb": "two",
"objectc": "three"
}

WOULD LIKE:
{
"objecta": "one",
"objectb": "two",
"objectc": "three",
"_text": "text"
}
```

Comment: Pass your own sort function as an argument to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Do not use an object if you care about order.

Answer (score 0):

You could first separate the strings into two arrays and sort them separately and then combine them. This will work if any other symbol are present.

```js
const items = {
  objectb: "text",
  objecta: "one",
  _text: "two",
  objectc: "three",
};

const strComparator = (a, b) => {
  if (a < b) return -1;
  if (a > b) return 1;
  return 0;
};

const ordered = Object.keys(items).reduce(
    (acc, curr) => {
      if (/[a-z]/i.test(curr[0])) acc[0].push(curr);
      else acc[1].push(curr);
      return acc;
    },[[], []])
  .flatMap((arr) => arr.sort(strComparator))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = items[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(ordered);
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to provide a sorting function

```
var array = ['_', 'a', 'b']

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  // sort _ at the end
  if (a[0] == '_' && b[0] != '_') return 1;
  if (a[0] != '_' && b[0] == '_') return -1;
  // sort by standard string comparison
  return a.localeCompare(b);
})
```

Comment: `localeCompare` is not the standard string comparison

Comment: The question is _"What would be the best way of sorting by Alphabetic, then symbols"_? The underscore at first position is obviously just an example.

Comment: my bad, may be an english language issue as i'm not a native english speaker. i meant standard as oposed to "default". indeed it's not the one sort use by default.

Comment: doest it answer the question then ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951167/sorting-in-javascript-with-special-characters